# I bought a figure of a girl with a baseball bat, but I don't know who of

Tags: merchandise

I was in Akibahara when I came across a load of stalls selling second-hand figures. I couldn't resist and bought some stuff from my favourite series. Also, I bought a figure of a schoolgirl with a baseball bat who seems to be floating on top of some water with lotus flowers.

[image]

There doesn't seem to be any company markings on it, apart from maybe a 'C' at the backside of the base. I don't have a ruler, but I estimate it to be about 5.5 inches tall. Unfortunately I don't speak Japanese, so I couldn't ask the seller.

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas what series she could be from? I'd really like to put a name to the face (and watch the series also)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

She seems to be [**Natsume Reiko**](http://www.natsumeyuujinchou.wikia.com/wiki/Reiko_Natsume) from [**Natsume Yuujinchou**](http://myanimelist.net/anime/4081/Natsume_Yuujinchou)

[image]

Sometimes, she's shown with a baseball bat with some seals on it, which she uses to fight youkai. This is a picture of her wielding the bat:

[image]

For extra confirmation, the same figure can be seen on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/switch-language/product/B00DT3RY6S/ref=dp_change_lang?ie=UTF8&language=en_JP) with 夏目友人帳 (Natsume Yuujinjou) and 夏目レイコ (Natsume Reiko) in the description.

Comment: using her name, I was able to find a site with the figure :) thanks

Comment: To add, the difference between Reiko and Madera in Reiko's form is that Reiko is depicted in having a bat while Madera  in Reiko's form does not (there is also the eyes but in terms of a figure it'd be a minute difference which could just be easily missed)